# Typescript Exclude refuses generic types

Tags: typescript

Here is a minimal reproducible example

```js
type Value = {}

type Something = {}

function isValid<T>(a: Exclude<T, Value>) { }

function selecter<T extends Something>(obj: T) {
    isValid(obj)
}

export { }
```

Typescript 3.8.3 refuses the *isEqual(obj)* expression

```js
Type 'Something' is not assignable to type 'Exclude<T, Value>
```

But *Type Something* is assignable! This works:

```js
let s: Something = {}
isValid(s)
```

Isn't the error message a bug? How can I make *isValid* accept any type except *Value*?

Comment: could you provide `isEqual` signature ? or maybe you meant `isValid(...)` in `selecter`

Comment: Sorry! I meant isValid. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Type miss match for arguments of isValid.

```
type Something {}

function isValid<T>(a: T) { }

function selecter<T extends Something>(obj: T) {
  isValid(obj)
}
```

Comment: With `Something` as an interface, both `isValid` statements fail to compile.
`Type 'Something' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

Comment: ok i get it, its a type miss match you see. you are passing in obj of type T into isValid.
But in your function definition of isValid you say its arguments are of type Exclude<T, Value>.